# inverse of $f:(0,4/9) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x - x^{3/2}$

Tags: inverse-function

I'm trying to find the inverse of $f(x)=x-x^{3/2}$ in the interval from zero to its maximum (at $x=4/9$). [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse%20of%20f%28x%29%20%3D%20x%20-%20x%5E%283%2F2%29) gives me an expression involving complex terms, but this is no good, as the formula will be part of a moodle calculated question that only
accepts reals. Any thoughts?

Comment: Solve $y=(\sqrt x)^2-(\sqrt x)^3$ for $\sqrt x$ using the cubic formula. I don't think there is an elementary real formula. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: Still representable by a nice [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. After changing variables so that $u = \sqrt{x}$, one gets $f(x) = x-x^{3/2} = u^2-u^3$. Thus, all one has to do is solve the cubic $u^3 - u^2 + y = 0$. This can be accomplished be means of a trigonometric identity ([Tschirnhaus-Vieta approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908861/using-trig-identity-to-solve-a-cubic-equation)).

Within the required range of $x$, which translates to $ u \in (0, 2/3) $, the solution is:
$$ u = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \cos \left[ \frac{1}{3} \arccos\left( 1- \frac{27}{2} y\right) - \frac{2\pi}{3} \right] $$